# Are certain cards exclusive to the mission zone?

Tags: ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3

In Ultimate Marvel vs Capcom 3 Heroes vs Heralds mode, are the cards I can obtain determined by the mission zone?  Or is there a possibility for me to obtain any card in any zone?  If it is determined by the zone, where can I find a list of what cards come from which zones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this blog [here.](http://shoryuken.com/2012/02/03/umvc3-heroes-heralds-card-locations-video-showcase/) It has a grid with a list of all the cards and in what location they can be obtained. Obviously I haven't check every single location, so your mileage may vary, but it's certainly a good place to start.

http://shoryuken.com/2012/02/03/umvc3-heroes-heralds-card-locations-video-showcase/

Comment: great chart.  The video in that link shows some sick combos